# Definining constrains with Python scipy.optimize.minimize

Tags: python, optimization, scipy, minimize, quantlib

I am working with a financial model in python and QuantLib to parametrize a Heston volatility surface model. When using the minimize module in scipy the algorithm still processes values outside of the given constrains. This kills my process as the QuantLib module returns an error and stops the run. This is unless I force conditions inside of the objective function declaration.

```
def f(params):
    params[4] = min(params[4], .999)
    params[4] = max(params[4], -.999)
    params[0] = max(params[0], 1e-8); params[1] = max(params[1], 1e-8)
    params[2] = max(params[2], 1e-8); params[3] = max(params[3], 1e-8)

    return hestonModelSurface(params, label="Model1").avgError
    # v0, kappa, theta, sigma, rho
cons = (
        {'type': 'ineq', 'fun': lambda x: x[0] - 0.001},
        {'type': 'ineq', 'fun': lambda x: .999 - x[0]},
        {'type': 'ineq', 'fun': lambda x: x[1] - 0.001},
        {'type': 'ineq', 'fun': lambda x: .999 - x[1]},
        {'type': 'ineq', 'fun': lambda x: x[2] - 0.001},
        {'type': 'ineq', 'fun': lambda x: .999 - x[2]},
        {'type': 'ineq', 'fun': lambda x: x[3] - 0.001},
        {'type': 'ineq', 'fun': lambda x: .999 - x[3]},
        {'type': 'ineq', 'fun': lambda x: .99 - x[4]**2}
        ) 
result = minimize(f, m1_params, constraints=cons, method="SLSQP")
hestonModel0 = hestonModelSurface(result["x"], label="Model0")
```

This is why I end up using manual constrains in the obj function such as 'params[4] = min(params[4], .999); params[4] = max(params[4], -.999)'.

Does anyone know how to force scipy not to include values outside the bounded constrains?

Comment: This isn't a minimal **reproducible** example. In the meantime, you can pass bounds on the variables via `minimize`s `bound` argument, see the docs for more details.

Comment: @joni Yes, this did it. I don't know how I did not see this before, I knew it was a dumb question.  Still I have seen many people not using bounds and still applying a manual fix in f for some reason.. Thanks